# Javascript Set, reference breaks when passing to function

Tags: javascript, set

tl;dr: When I pass a Set to child functions which in turn adds new values to the Set, the new values are not added to the original Set. I find this wierd since it Set is an object. Why is this so?

I am building a web crawler in Node, which I will use to visit all pages on a domain.
The basic algorithm is as follows:

1. Visit a page.
2. Save the url in a collection that contains all visited links.
3. Extract all links not yet visited.
4. Repeat 1-3 for all new links.

I use a Set as a container for the links, since lookup complexity is O(1). I initalize the Set before I start visiting the links, and pass it into the function that contains the logic. The problem is that when I add the link to the Set, it is not there the next time the function is called. It appears as when I pass the Set to a function, a new object is created. How do I get around this?

```
async function initialize() {
  const visitedLinks = new Set();
  await scrapePage(ROOT_URL, visitedLinks);
}

async function scrapePage(url, visitedLinks) {
  let body = (await axios.get(url)).data;
  // Here I add the url to visitedLinks
  visitedLinks.add(url);
  
  const links = getLinks(body);
  const linksNotVisited = getLinksNotVisited(
    links,
    visitedLinks
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < linksNotVisited.length; i++) {
    await scrapePage(linksNotVisited[i], visitedLinks);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's `getLinksNotVisited()`?

Comment: Can you make this an actual [mcve] (with dummy data) that shows the problem?

Comment: Ok, I will do that, brb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when I add the link to the Set, it is not there the next time the function is called.

No, that's not the problem. The `Set` is working fine, and doesn't change its identitiy.

The problem is that you're adding the links to the set at the wrong time, in a recursive function. By adding an url only when you actually visit it, it can happen that when multiple pages point to the same url, that url becomes part of multiple `linksNotVisited` arrays (at different recursive calls), and will then be visited multiple times.

Instead, check whether a link has been visited right before loading that page:

```
async function scrapePage(url, visitedLinks) {
  if (visitedLinks.has(url)) return;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  let body = (await axios.get(url)).data;

  visitedLinks.add(url);
  
  for (const link of getLinks(body)) {
    // the if statement would work if put here as well,
    // but it's cleaner as a base case of the recursion
    await scrapePage(link, visitedLinks);
  }
}
```

or alternatively keep a set of `linksNoLongerToBeVisited` that you immediately fill when adding a link to the array that is iterated afterwards:

```
async function scrapePage(url, linksNoLongerToBeVisited) {
  let body = (await axios.get(url)).data;
  const links = getLinks(body);
  const linksNotVisited = links.filter(link => {
    if (linksNoLongerToBeVisited.has(link)) return false;
    linksNoLongerToBeVisited.add(link);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return true;
  });

  for (const link of links) {
    await scrapePage(link, linksNoLongerToBeVisited);
  }
}
```

---

Btw, if you don't need the recursive structure for anything, this function might be easier to write in an iterative fashion using the `Set` as a queue:

```
async function initialize() {
  const visits = new Set([ROOT_URL]);
  for (const url of visits) {
    const body = (await axios.get(url)).data;
    for (const link of getLinks(body)) {
      visits.add(link);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I made a big mistake when I posted the question. I removed some code to make the question easier to read, and mistakenly removed the code that checks if the url is in the list in precisely the place where you suggested. So there is something else going on here...

Comment: @hellogoodnight You might want to [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) then where you include a [mcve] that we can execute to see what doesn't work.